# stuck on gmaps4rails data from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I would like to take an array and load the data into the json object, but i am stuck on exactly how to do it.

TripsController

```
def index
@trips = Trip.all
@markers = Array.new
@trips.each do |trip|
  for marker in trip.markers
    @markers.push(marker)
  end
end

@gmaps_options =
{
  "markers"     => { "data" => '[{ "lng": "-99.9018131", "lat": "31.9685988"},
                                 { "lng": "-102.552784", "lat": "23.634501"},
                                 { "lng": "-122.3667", "lat": "40.5833"},
                                 { "lng": "-121.8356", "lat": "39.7400"}
                                  ]', },
  "polylines"   => { "data" => ' [ [
                     {"lng": -99.9018131, "lat": 31.9685988},
                     {"lng": -102.552784, "lat": 23.634501},
                     ], [
                      { "lng": "-122.3667", "lat": "40.5833"},
                      { "lng": "-121.8356", "lat": "39.7400"}
                      ] ]' }
}

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @trips }
  end 
end
```

The longitude and latitude are hardcoded right now but i would like to load the @markers into the longitude latitude,

```
"lng": @markers[0].longitude, "lat": @markers[0].latitude
```

This makes the map not render, just a gray box.

In the view the map is called with gmaps(@gmaps_options)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like you have your variable reference inside of a quoted string.

try adding the value to the string

```
'[{ "lng":' + @markers[0].longitude.to_s + ', "lat": @markers[0].latitude ....'
```